# Is "hell of a" positive or negative?

Tags: etymology, phrases

I find it a very curious thing that the phrase "hell of a" seems to be suitable to describe both good and bad things.

e.g.

> It was a great party. We had a **hell of a** time.

vs

> We sold the house eventually. But we had a **hell of a** time.

I certainly hear it more commonly used as in the first instance, but I imagine that this is a regional thing. But I wonder which sense came first. What is the etymology of the phrase?

And, with this in mind, how should I interpret a sentence with very little context?

e.g.

> We had a **hell of a** time when we visited my parents over Christmas.

Comment: related: [Clarifying the usage of “hella”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51131)

Comment: It's part of the cluster of [taboo terms and euphemisms surrounding the word _Hell_.](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/thehell.html) It can be positive, negative, or neutral, depending on the idiom used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The phrase "a hell of a time" contains two idioms. "A hell of" and "a time".

As other answers have said "a hell of" just emphasises the strength of something.

> That man has a hell of a cheek
>
> She has a hell of a talent
>
> He has a hell of a big nose

... and so on.

"A time" often refers to a period that was interesting in some unspecified way, especially when preceded with a strengthening adjective.

> He had quite a time during his illness
>
> What a time we had on holiday!

Put them together, and you have:

> We had a hell of a time.

There is nothing in the sentence to say whether they had a hell of a good time, a hell of an exciting time, a hell of a bad time, a hell of a dreary time. All of that is to be inferred from context.

And perhaps the speaker doesn't want you to know the truth.

Related: if you say "I had a hellish time", that's always bad.

Answer (score 5):

It refers to the *extremity* of goodness or badness.

Answer (score 3):

"hell of a" as an idiom is merely superlative, strengthening the noun that follows.

That said, we generally use it to imply a ***great (amount of)*** in the positive sense.  In the negative sense, it would be just 'hell'.

Comment: How would this work for the phrase "a hell of a time"? How can "time" be strengthened?

Comment: It is not *time* itself that is intensified as you seem to understand *time* literally -- it is the experience implied by *time*. So whatever experience it was, it was too good/ too bad. A 'good time' is a good experience over a time, right?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary of idioms: **A hell of a time**- A difficult task, an awful time.

Example:

> When he's drunk I have **a hell of a time** getting his car keys. He
>   doesn't want to give me his keys.

Similar idiom :

> a dickens of a time , one hell of a time.

N.B. They all mean the same- dealing with one very difficult task, one major problem.

Slang:

> **a hell of a time** - extremely good spend time.

"**Hell of a**" refers to [something impressive, extremely good](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-of/hell-of-a). It is mostly vulgar and American slang.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase, 'a hell of a thing', as in any other phrase containing the 'hell of a', string can be either negative or positive, each one only depending upon the context it is used in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the phrase "hell of a time" might have originated shortly before WWI with a Brit named Flynn Mitchell I suspect was a music hall entertainer.  I'm basing this on a hint on page 176 of the book "On the Front Line:  True World War One Stories," edited by C.B. Purdom.